# Open Set Under Integer Set

Tags: real-analysis

I have a confusion regarding open set. This answer  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158238 states that -> i) S⊂R  is open iff for all s ∈ S, there exists an interval of the form (a,b) such that s ∈ (a,b) ⊂ S. ii) If C is a closed set, then R∖C is open (and Vice-Versa) and iii) union of open sets is open.

Now, if I take an set Z (Integer set) instead of R, is the subset {1} open or closed?  According to the first definition if I take S = (0,2) I can say that {1} is open.

But I can write {1} as -: Z - (−∞,1) U (1,∞) ((ii) + (iii) combined) which should make it a closed set.

What am I missing here? Can I not define an open or closed set in Integer set? Or there's something wrong I am presuming ?

Comment: Sets are not doors. They can be open, closed, both or neither

Comment: Thanks. Will Remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking at $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the induced topology, then you obtain nothing other than the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, ie every singleton $\{n\}$ is open and closed in $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, $$\{n\}=\mathbb{Z} \cap (n-1/2,n+1/2)=\mathbb{Z}\cap [n-1/2,n+1/2]$$

This shows that $\{n\}$ can be written as the intersection of $\mathbb{Z}$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, as well as with a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. This topology is not really interesting, because every subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is now open and closed.

If you want another example of a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, you may want to consider the topology having finite subset as closed subsets, for instance.

Comment: Any topology where every set is open and closed is called a discrete topology. Though it's not very interesting in it's own, it's a good example of a totally disconnected space. Totally disconnected spaces are pretty interesting :-)